# I need help understanding the Pattern code in the grep function

Tags: r

This is a code from a datacamp.com quiz for the intermediate R course.

I don't understand how the pattern `"^[0-9]+$"` works.
 Can someone please explain this?

```
dates <- c("12/15/10", "12-2012", "12.2014", "1995")
grep(pattern = "^[0-9]+$", x = dates)
```

the output is 4

Comment: `help(regex)` is a good starting point

Comment: You can also plug a pattern into an online regular expression tool, e.g. https://regexr.com/488lh

Comment: a good place to play around with regex is here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Regular expressions are both an art and a curse (https://xkcd.com/1171/, https://xkcd.com/1313/). There are several good (and many more not-as-good) tutorials and references for learning and experimenting with regex, including the already-mentioned https://regexr.com/, as well as https://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: See the resources provided by people above but to explain exactly the pattern you are using the `^` and `$` are boundary characters marking the start and end of a line. `[0-9]` is any number between 0 and 9 the `+` repeats the previous pattern until it doesn't match. The grep function will return the position of the match, so in your vector the only match is 1995 the fourth item

Comment: @George so that would mean for each element of the vector the function checks if its a number between 0-9 and if it does not satisfy at any point, it would move on to the next element. for 12/15/10 the pattern would fail after 2 due to the '/' and move on to the next element. Just so I know, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Vik It would be slightly more sophisticated and would search the whole string for any instance the meets your pattern criteria. In your example, it checks that the entire string is numbers. If you only had `[0-9]` as your pattern then everything would be returned because it is asking "Is there one or more numbers (0-9) anywhere in the string", so for example even "abc123" would also match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to regular expressions

```
^ - Stands for beginning of the string
[0-9] - Numeric values 
+ -   One or more characters can satisfy the criteria 
$ -  Should check for the character that satisfy the criteria till the end of string
```

For the input "12/15/10", "12-2012", "12.2014", "1995"

The method goes through each value and returns the sum of characters in the string that satisfy the regular expression.

In your example, The condition to satisfy is "A string with only numeric characters"

```
"12/15/10"  ===  Two "/" are the non numeric character.
 "12-2012"  ===  One "-" is a non numeric character.
 "12.2014"  ===  One "." is a non numeric character.
 "1995"     ===  Zero non numeric character. [Satisfy the criteria]
```

1995 is at a index of 4 in the input vector.

If in case your input was 
dates <- c("12/15//10", "12-2012", "12.20.14", "1995","1987")
grep(pattern = "^[0-9]+$", x = dates)

The output would be a vector with value  4  5  indicating the index of the values that satisfying the criteria.

Comment: did you mean "...returns the sum of characters in the string that do NOT satisfy the regular expression?"

Comment: No, it returns the index of the strings in the vector that satisfy the regular expression . In R vector index begins from 1. Therefore in the sample 1995 which satisfy the criteria is at a index 4 in the dates vector